# The proof of a property of mirror descent

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I am learning mirror descent, which basically states that we can solve a maximization problem of $L$ by iteratively solving
$$
x^k=\mathop{\arg\max}_{x} \{L(x)-\eta^{-1}D(x,x^{k-1})\}.
$$
Here $x$ is specified by a probability distribution and $D$ is the KL-divergence.

What I don't see is the following claim
$$
L(x^k)-\eta^{-1}D(x^k,x^{k-1})\ge L(x^*)-\eta^{-1}D(x^*,x^{k-1}){\color{red}{+\eta^{-1} D(x^*,\pi^k)}}
$$

It obviously holds if we ignore the red term. I don't really know why it is a direct result of mirror descent.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.